# Auto Increment with two primary keys

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL table with two fields as primary key (ID & RX), RX has AUTO_INCREMENT. This results in the following SQL table:

```
 ID    |  RX
------------------
 1     |     1
 1     |     2
 2     |     3
 2     |     4
```

However, I expected the following result :

```
 ID    |  RX
------------------
 1     |     1
 1     |     2
 2     |     1
 2     |     2
```

What is wrong in my configuration? How can I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Why would you expect auto_increment to go 1, 2, 1, 2

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT is not valid sql server syntax. In sql server we have identity. Regardless, it does NOT reset for a new value in another column.

Comment: auto increment isn't going to handle this for you.  You'll have to query for the max RX for a given ID and increment it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that with autoincrement.

But using your current table you can calculate the second id, and use a VIEW to show the second ID

```
 SELECT ID, RX, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID
                           ORDER BY RX) as RX_2
 FROM yourTable
```